# Topshelf have different behavior when a start my service from services.msc

Tags: windows-services, log4net, topshelf

I have created a monitor windows service using TopShelf and Log4net for logging.

When I run my application from command line, I get 'Started' in my log file.

When I install my service from command line 'myservice install' and then I start it from service.msc, I also get 'Started' in my log file.

When I install and start my service using then command line 'myservice install start', my service is installed and it starts, but I don't get 'Started' in my log file.

```
       private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

            HostFactory.Run(x =>
            {
                x.UseLog4Net();

                x.Service<MonitorService>(s =>
                {
                    s.ConstructUsing(name => new MonitorService());
                    s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());
                    s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());
                });
                x.RunAsLocalSystem();

                x.SetDescription("Monitor Service");
                x.SetDisplayName("Monitor Service");
                x.SetServiceName("MonitorService");
            });
```

My Monitor Service class:

```
public class MonitorService 
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public MonitorData GetData()
    {
        return new MonitorData();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        HostLogger.Get<MonitorService>().Info("Started");
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        HostLogger.Get<MonitorService>().Info("Stopped");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real difference between running it yourself and running the service is the context the app runs in. This is most likely a permissions issue.